# DD4T 2 with Tridion 9

Tags: sdl-tridion, dd4t-2

I need to write .net application using DD4T and Tridion 9. Please suggest the steps that I can follow ?

Comment: Hi Sikarwar. That's a pretty vague question; do you have a working content manager with publishing setup? If not, I'd start there. DD4T is a delivery framework that you'll use to publish content as JSON, and then consume that same content on the delivery side - but you can worry about that once publishing is working. 

I'd recommend going through the Sites 9 documentation (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/) and then the DD4T docs later on, but again - if you ask a more specific question you might have more luck.

Comment: Thanks. When I use this code to render the template , @Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView("Article"), I get this error -  "Controller was not configured in component template metadata or in application settings. Unable to Render component presentation."

Comment: @JoshHebb Yes, we do have working Tridion 9 publishing setup.

Comment: I am able to run the DD4T 2.0 application against Tridion 2013, I need to run the same against Tridion 9. Please suggest, what all config changes I need to make?

Comment: @Sikarwar - Reading through the comments, it sounds like your real issue is that you're having problems rendering 'Article' component presentations. Can you update the question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use one of the Html.RenderXXX methods in DD4T, the component presentations will be rendered with a controller and action. You need to create this controller first, by extending the DD4T.Mvc.Controller.ModelControllerBase class, like this:

```
public ComponentPresentationController : ModelControllerBase
{
    public ComponentPresentationController(IPageFactory pageFactory, IComponentPresentationFactory componentPresentationFactory, ILogger logger, IDD4TConfiguration dd4tConfiguration, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory) : 
       : base (pageFactory, componentPresentationFactory, logger, dd4tConfiguration, viewModelFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

Next, you need to tell DD4T that you want to use this controller to render component presentations. You do this by adding the following to your Web.config:

```
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationController" value="Component" /> 
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationAction" value="ComponentModel" />
```